# Proof for corollary of Lagrange's theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I first give the definition of index of a subgroup:

> Definition
>
> Let $H\leq G$
>   The index of $H \in G$ is the distinct right coset of $H \in G$ denoted $\left | G:H \right |$
>
> Corollary:
>   If $H \leq G$ is finite then $\left | H \right | | \left | G \right |$
>
> Corollary:
>   $g\in G$ implies $\left | g \right | | \left | G \right | $
>
> Proof:$ \left | g \right |=\left | \left \langle g \right \rangle \right |$

could someone kindly shed some light on this proof? This proof follows from the criterion for $\left \langle a^{i} \right \rangle=\left \langle a^{j} \right \rangle$ but I am unclear how it prove the  corollary.

Answer (score 0):

Every element $g \in G$ will generate a cyclic subgroup, therefore 
if $H_g = \langle g \rangle$, then  $|g| = |H_g|$ | $ |G|$ (by Lagrange's theorem)

Comment: Thanks! It appeared that
If $g\in G then <g> is a subgroup of G slipped my mind